# Android Event Detection

Tags: android, events, detection

How does Android detect events? I'm not asking about implementing different handlers for events, but the logic on decide the event types. For example, when the user performs a swipe on the screen, where the Android SDK detects that this is a swipe event instead of a scroll event or other events? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Android does not have Events like you may be used to in javascript or WinForms.  @TedHopp 's answer is correct.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Touch events are typically interpreted by a [`GestureDetector`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html). Typically, touch events are handled by a `View` by simply passing them to a `GestureDetector`. The `GestureDetector` detects when there is some particular gesture (tap, fling, etc.) by analyzing the recent history of touch events. The `GestureDetector` then notifies one of the registered listeners (often a subclass of [`SimpleOnGestureListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html)).

It's up to the listener to decide what the semantic meaning is of the gesture. For instance, a `ScrollView` will set an `OnGestureListener` that reacts to a fling event by scrolling rapidly. A custom view might react to a fling by deleting some object from the view.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Do you have any idea of where exactly in the SDK Android decides it's a touch event or a tap event, and for a touch event, where in the GestureDetector analyze the touch events and decide it's tap, fling, etc. ?

Comment: @user1858060 - Do you mean where in the source code? You can find `GestureDetector` [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/GestureDetector.java).

Comment: Thanks! But it seems that whether the event is click, longclick, or complex gesture, etc. is not decided in this class.

Comment: @user1858060 - Sure it is. You need to look down near the end of the file, past all the inner class and interface declarations. Look for `onTouchEvent`, which is the driver for all detection decisions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!! I read that part of code. It seems to me that it's only handling touch events. I'm wondering where Android dispatch the events to onClick(), onLongClick(), or onTouch()? Also, where Android dispatch the events to a specific view?

Comment: @user1858060 - There's [a nice article here](http://cjix.info/blog/misc/internal-input-event-handling-in-the-linux-kernel-and-the-android-userspace/) describing the internals of event handling at the Linux kernel and Android userspace levels. Perhaps that's what you are looking for. At even lower levels, events are handled by device drivers and are highly hardware dependent.

Comment: @user1858060 - Also take a look at [the source for View](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java), particularly the `performClick()` method and where it is called from.